# Application-wide globals in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Does Vue.js have an idiomatic way of declaring application-wide globals like `baseUrl` and then referencing them throughout the app (for API calls etc)?

If so, what is the best way to configure such globals at build-time to create development, test and prod instances? For example, I imagine doing `export BASEURL='http://dev.myapp.com'`, running a build and getting an app with this baseUrl configured. This would in turn allow me to create automated builds for Continuous Delivery certain branches are updated (`develop` -> `dev.myapp.com`, `master` -> `www.myapp.com` etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do: use some state management tool, like [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

If you don't want to add complexity to your app, I use a parent Vue instance, let say `App.vue` and define global data in that instance, then when I need that data from the parent I call `this.$root.baseUrl` in case you want the baseUrl. Notice that you can also call `this.$parent.baseUrl` but this will only work for direct childs, if you are inside a child of a child, you wont get the global data, that's why is better the `$root` object.